# Is there any way how to get HttpResponseMessage.Content body when response is HttpStatusCode.NoContent?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I am using C# and .NET Core 3.0

Currently when I send GET request to a server and it returns response with status **204**, then it seems that `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` strips body from it and I cannot read its content.

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,$"/gettask.ashx?testerror=20");
var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

I know the server is returning also body when status is 204. I have tested it with Curl and it returns this body for 204 `{ "nextRequestInSec" : 10 }`.

Verbose response from curl:

```
curl http://address.dom/testerror=204 -v
*   Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to address.dom (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) port 80 (#0)
> GET testerror=204 HTTP/1.1
> Host: address.dom
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
< Cache-Control: private
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
< X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Wed, 20 Nov 2019 13:45:00 GMT
<
{ "nextRequestInSec" : 10 }* Connection #0 to host address.dom left intact
```

For other responses (200, 401, 403, 404, 420, 500) it works correctly and I can read body as well.

Is there any way how to get to this body?

Comment: It would appear as though you are not able to get it: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/0cc22ccba707d7552159363d586262fa9c4e8a2a/src/System.Net.HttpListener/src/System/Net/HttpListenerResponse.cs#L83

Comment: Are you _sure_ curl displays the body? I was sceptical, so i ran a test myself, and it cuts off the response

Comment: @richzilla I have edited the question - look at the curl response there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @peinarydevelopment mentions in their comment, the `httpclient` instance will not return a body for status codes that dont support one. The best solution to your problem is to fix the server (or ask whoever is responsible for it).

If you really must deal with the broken HTTP server, you could drop down to TCP level and retrieve the packets directly from the socket, put that seems like a very long way around the problem.

Answer (score 0):

204 means there is no content, so before reading the content check the status code.
If you want to return data, change your status code because 204 should not.

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,$"/gettask.ashx?testerror=20");
var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
var responseContent = (response.IsSuccessStatusCode && response.StatusCode !=204)? await 
                      response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync():null;
```

Comment: Well generally - 204 is just a status and body is body. It shouldn't matter which status I receive...

Comment: A status is made for something, like the way of parsing the response

Comment: You are correct - I was looking at it the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Well it appears that I was a bit blinded. The truth is that in .NET Core **this is not possible** according to the [HttpClient](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/e99ec129cfd594d53f4390bf97d1d736cff6f860/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/HttpConnection.cs#L602-L606)

Also if You look at it as the HTTP communication, it should follow [HTTP specification](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.5), which says, that:

> The 204 response MUST NOT include a message-body, and thus is always terminated by the first empty line after the header fields.